# What is the fastest library for finding FFT on a GPU?

Tags: cuda, opencl, fft, gpu, gpgpu

Which is the fastest library to find FFT on a GPU? Please give answers for both NVIDIA and ATI cards. Also, if possible give timing figures.

Thanks.

Comment: libjacket (C/C++, I believe) for cuda is pretty fast.  I don't have any timing info.  It's commercial, though.

Comment: How about you go out and try them? I doubt you have very many choices.

Answer (score 4):

For NVidia GPUs, look at the [CUFFT library](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1_1/CUFFT_Library_1.1.pdf). As far as I can tell, AMD has not productized FFT on ATI GPUs yet, but it might be worth looking at the [ACML-GPU](http://developer.amd.com/libraries/acmlgpu/Pages/default.aspx) library. You could also try looking at [OpenCL FFT libraries](http://www.bealto.com/gpu-fft_intro.html) which *should* work on both GPUs.

Giving timing figures is impossible, because it varies so much depending on the actual hardware you have, your problem size, etc.

Comment: [link]http://developer.amd.com/libraries/appmathlibs/pages/default.aspx [/link] APPML-FFT is available for ATI GPUs, but they are very slow as compared to the CUFFT library.

Comment: The lack of authoritative figures leads one to dream up a massive benchmarking run.

Answer (score 4):

The [NukadaFFT](http://matsu-www.is.titech.ac.jp/~nukada/nufft/) library is supposed to be the highest performance FFT implementation on NVIDIA hardware. There are links to papers which document the performance of the library - in some cases throughput is claimed to 25% higher than running the same FFT using CUFFT. That comes at a price in flexibility, because the code only supports up to radix 32 transforms.